Trouble compiling c++ connectors in Visual Studio Code, Mac M1
There's a very good and comprehensive post here that will help beginners to comprehend the problem. But I think my post is still relevant because it refers specifically to arm64 architecture and macOS.
I've trying to use C++ connectors for MySQL and PostgreSQL. For the first I used the official MySQL C++ connector, while for Postgres, libpqxx. The thing is I always get the same errors. I'm using a Mac M1 and the errors copied are from the MySQL connector.
When using the Visual Studio Code debbuger (using clang++), the result is,
/usr/bin/clang++ -std=gnu++14 -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g /Users/kakolu/VisualStudioCode/my.cpp -o /Users/kakolu/VisualStudioCode/my
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "check(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&)", referenced from:
      check_lib() in my-6afd68.o
  "check(std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>>> const&)", referenced from:
      check_lib() in my-6afd68.o
  "__get_driver_instance_by_name", referenced from:
      get_driver_instance_by_name(char const*) in my-6afd68.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

On the other hand, when using the command clang++ my.cpp -o my the result is a bunch of errors. I paste some of them but not all:
In file included from my.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-9.0.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/connection.h:41:
In file included from /usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-9.0.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/variant.h:44:
/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-9.0.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:91:11: error: exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version
   91 |   virtual ~SQLException() noexcept {};
      |           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/stdexcept:115:3: note: overridden virtual function is here
  115 |   ~runtime_error() _NOEXCEPT override;
      |   ^
In file included from my.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-9.0.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/connection.h:41:
In file included from /usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-9.0.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/variant.h:44:
/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-9.0.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:91:26: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
   91 |   virtual ~SQLException() noexcept {};
      |                          ^
      |                          ;
/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-9.0.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:94:3: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
   94 |   MEMORY_ALLOC_OPERATORS(SQLException)
      |   ^
/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-9.0.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:46:37: note: expanded from macro 'MEMORY_ALLOC_OPERATORS'
   46 |   void* operator new(size_t, void*) noexcept; \
      |                                     ^
/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-9.0.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:94:3: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-9.0.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:47:53: note: expanded from macro 'MEMORY_ALLOC_OPERATORS'
   47 |   void* operator new(size_t, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept; \

What am I dong wrong? With the libpqxx library is very similar. Any advice or guidance appreciated. Thanks beforehand!
The code I'm using is the one provided in the official webpage:
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' »
   AS _message'..." << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " »
     << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

I'm trying to compile a c++ connector using Visual Studio Code installed in a Mac M1. I'm expecting the program to compile.

compiling c++ connectors in Visual Studio Code vscode is a editor with extensions and does not compile your code. Which compiler/version are you actually using?

Your first command needs to link to the mysql libraries. Your second is missing -std=gnu++14 which results in clang using c++98 which is presumably not supported by the mysql library

Thank you both. I'm using Apple clang version 16.0.0. I noticed the  -std=gnu++14, also have tried with -std=c/gnu++17,20,23 but nothing. It seems to be there by default. How do I change it?

You shouldn't need to change it, it's not causing your problem. As to where to change it that depends on how you're building your code

I see. After researching I think it has to do with the linking of the libraries. The thing is that I've tried with the -L flag in task.jason also from terminal, the LDFLAG is also in .zprofile, but it says it cannot find the libraries. The command I'm using is clang++ -L/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-9.0.0/lib64/ my.cpp -o my  -stdlib=libc++ -libmysqlcppconn-static.a.

Are the mysql libraries built for arm or lintel?

Homebrew is configured to download for arm64 architecture, so I suppose they are correct.

Please show the full output of your updated compiler command

I just switched to SQLite and is working fine. Still don't know why libpqxx doesn't work but I appreciate your help. I'm confident I will solve the other problem in the future.
